# Second ListView showing up with a new array

Tags: android, arrays, android-arrayadapter

I have 2 arrays:
Array1: A B C D E F
Array2: A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3 ...

ListView1 |  ListView2

---

```
 A     |   A1 A2 A3 A4
 B     |   B1 B2 B3
 C     |   C1 C2 C3 C4
 D     |   D1 D2
 E     |   E1 E2
 F     |   F1 F2 F3
```

I would like to first show a single ListView containing Array1. Once an item is selected that item will highlight or all the rest will disappear, also a new ListView will show up right next to first ListView with Array2.

Let's say I picked C:

ListView1 |  ListView2

---

```
 A     |   C1
 B     |   C2
*C*    |   C3
 D     |   C4
 E     |      
 F     |
```

I can do the first part, and can handle onItemClick event, but not sure how to create a new ListView after that with the second array.

Comment: can you show your code to load second listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create something like this.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterOne = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.your_layout, listOne);
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterTwo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.your_layout, listTwo); 
listViewOne.setAdapter(arrayAdapterOne);
listViewTwo.setAdapter(arrayAdapterTwo);                

listViewOne.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int pos, long arg3) {

    // your logic here
    //update list two as per value of list One
    arrayAdapterTwo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.your_layout, listTwo); 
    arrayAdapterTwo.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // or
    // listViewTwo.setAdapter(arrayAdapterTwo);             

    }
});
```